# Embedded VF Page Not Responding To StandardController

Tags: visualforce, sobject, standardcontroller, extension, embedded

I am trying to embed a custom VF page into my Accounts layout. I believe my error is in the standardController. I assumed it should be SObject but it did not work and now I am not 100% sure what it should be. I have tried a number of variations with no luck. Is the standardController where I am going wrong? Any advice to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

I am getting error

> Unknown constructor
>   'noteandtask_controller.noteandtask_controller(ApexPages.StandardController controller)'

VF Code:

```
    <apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="noteandtask_controller">
        <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!tasksAndNotes}" var="record">
        .....
    </apex:page>
```

APEX Code:

```
public class noteandtask_controller {
public List<SObject> tasksAndNotes {get; private set;}
public List<SObject> t {get;set;}
public List<SObject> n {get;set;}

public noteandtask_controller(){
    tasksAndNotes = new List<SObject>();
    t = [Select CreatedById, Subject, Description, CreatedDate From Task];
    n = [Select CreatedById, Title, Body,CreatedDate From Note];
    tasksAndNotes.addAll(t);
    tasksAndNotes.addAll(n);

    System.debug('the  t list is: ' + t);
    System.debug('the  n list is: ' + n);
    System.debug('the tasksAndNotes list is: ' + tasksAndNotes);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are extending a standard controller then the extension controller class requires a standardcontroller as a constructor parameter

So your constructor will look like below

```
public noteandtask_controller(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){
  tasksAndNotes = new List<SObject>();
  t = [Select CreatedById, Subject, Description, CreatedDate From Task];
  n = [Select CreatedById, Title, Body,CreatedDate From Note];
  tasksAndNotes.addAll(t);
  tasksAndNotes.addAll(n);

   System.debug('the  t list is: ' + t);
   System.debug('the  n list is: ' + n);
   System.debug('the tasksAndNotes list is: ' + tasksAndNotes);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried that earlier and for some reason my developer console is lagging. I had to save it and close out of the console 3 times before the changes took. Frustrating. But thank you for confirming that this is what needed to happen!

Answer (score 2):

Change your constructor of your extension class into:

```
public noteandtask_controller(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){
//...
```

And your issue will be gone. For a standardcontroller extension class, the constructor needs to take standardController as the parameter